# Sirikit launching the app fully instead of showing in own scroll

Tags: ios

I have just created single view controller app and adding targets with Siri extensions( intents and intent ui extension).
But when I say Siri command to start the intent it just launching the app instead of showing in Siri view itself. Since I have started exploring Siri please let me know the issue and if any tutorial I can go through

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? Having the same problem now.

Comment: what's the solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The bug was that the extension's plist contained the wrong entry in `NSExtensions->NSExtensionAttributes->IntentsSupported` – obviously the default Xcode actions are incorrect.

What you need to state there are the actual *class names* of the intents you handle, *not* their names as per the `intentdefinition` file.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling 'copy only when installing' under Embed App Extensions in main target build phases fix the issue for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps:-

- Add intents and intentsUI(if you need to customize default UI) as
  extension
- Override the Intent handers
- Mention your intents in info.plist
- Allow app to be accible by siri in phone settings

The best way to start is to go thru the [SiriKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH11-SW1)

Also, you can get some [sample code from Apple here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/IntentHandling/Introduction/Intro.html)